# DB2 Drop multiple tables - auto-generating script

Tags: sql, db2

I have some very specific issue. 
Target is to drop multiple tables in one schema that are older than 3 months and have certain prefix.

The difficulty is that I need to desing a script, that will generate drop statements automatically, so that I could shedule it to a crontab for daily execution.

Shortly, I need this two actions:

```
db2 "Select 'DROP TABLE ', tabname, ';' from syscat.tables where owner='DBUSER'" >> filename

db2 -tvf filename>log
```

been packed in a script that will generate the list of tables to be dropped and then drop those tables.

Actually, I have no idea how to do that... Please, give an advice.

Many thanks!

Comment: Not sure what your question is. Did you try running those two commands? Was the result as expected?

Answer (score 0):

This script should provide a basis for you to move forward:

```
DROPFILE=/tmp/drop.$$.sql
echo ${DROPFILE}

db2 -o connect to pocdb

#
# Drop / Create tables for clean environment
#
for i in 0 1 2 3 4 5
do
    db2 "drop table stkdrp.t${i}"
    db2 "create table stkdrp.t${i} (f1 integer)"
done

#
# List tables, there should be six
#
db2 "select count(*) as tabcnt from syscat.tables where tabschema like 'STKDRP%' "
db2 "select tabschema, tabname from syscat.tables where tabschema like 'STKDRP%' order by tabname"

#
# Create the drop command file
#
db2 "select 'DROP TABLE ' || trim(tabschema) || '.' || trim(tabname) || ';' from syscat.tables where tabschema like 'STKDRP%'" 2>&1 | grep DROP > ${DROPFILE}

#
# Drop the tables
#
db2 -tvf ${DROPFILE}

#
# List tables, there should be zero (0)
#
db2 "select count(*) as tabcnt from syscat.tables where tabschema like 'STKDRP%' "
db2 "select tabschema, tabname from syscat.tables where tabschema like 'STKDRP%' order by tabname"

#
# Clean up the mess
# 
rm -f ${DROPFILE}

db2 connect reset
db2 terminate
```

**Results:**

```
/tmp/drop.1607.sql

   Database Connection Information

 Database server        = DB2/LINUXX8664 10.5.3
 SQL authorization ID   = DB2INST1
 Local database alias   = POCDB

DB21034E  The command was processed as an SQL statement because it was not a 
valid Command Line Processor command.  During SQL processing it returned:
SQL0204N  "STKDRP.T0" is an undefined name.  SQLSTATE=42704
DB20000I  The SQL command completed successfully.
DB21034E  The command was processed as an SQL statement because it was not a 
valid Command Line Processor command.  During SQL processing it returned:
SQL0204N  "STKDRP.T1" is an undefined name.  SQLSTATE=42704
DB20000I  The SQL command completed successfully.
DB21034E  The command was processed as an SQL statement because it was not a 
valid Command Line Processor command.  During SQL processing it returned:
SQL0204N  "STKDRP.T2" is an undefined name.  SQLSTATE=42704
DB20000I  The SQL command completed successfully.
DB21034E  The command was processed as an SQL statement because it was not a 
valid Command Line Processor command.  During SQL processing it returned:
SQL0204N  "STKDRP.T3" is an undefined name.  SQLSTATE=42704
DB20000I  The SQL command completed successfully.
DB21034E  The command was processed as an SQL statement because it was not a 
valid Command Line Processor command.  During SQL processing it returned:
SQL0204N  "STKDRP.T4" is an undefined name.  SQLSTATE=42704
DB20000I  The SQL command completed successfully.
DB21034E  The command was processed as an SQL statement because it was not a 
valid Command Line Processor command.  During SQL processing it returned:
SQL0204N  "STKDRP.T5" is an undefined name.  SQLSTATE=42704
DB20000I  The SQL command completed successfully.

TABCNT
-----------
          6

  1 record(s) selected.


TABSCHEMA TABNAME                                                                                                     
---------- -----------
STKDRP   T0                                                                                                          
STKDRP   T1                                                                                                          
STKDRP   T2                                                                                                          
STKDRP   T3                                                                                                          
STKDRP   T4                                                                                                          
STKDRP   T5                                                                                                          

  6 record(s) selected.

DROP TABLE STKDRP.T0
DB20000I  The SQL command completed successfully.

DROP TABLE STKDRP.T1
DB20000I  The SQL command completed successfully.

DROP TABLE STKDRP.T2
DB20000I  The SQL command completed successfully.

DROP TABLE STKDRP.T3
DB20000I  The SQL command completed successfully.

DROP TABLE STKDRP.T4
DB20000I  The SQL command completed successfully.

DROP TABLE STKDRP.T5
DB20000I  The SQL command completed successfully.


TABCNT
-----------
          0

  1 record(s) selected.


TABUTHEMA  TABNAME                                                                                                     
---------- -------

  0 record(s) selected.

DB20000I  The SQL command completed successfully.
DB20000I  The TERMINATE command completed successfully.
```